# How to sort on title with relationsship

Tags: php, laravel

I have following query:  `$scholen = Scholen::with('media', 'translations', 'seo')->online()`

when i dump it:
[image]

How can i sort the schools on 'title' from the relations -> translations -> fields

Thanks in advance.

Olivier

Answer (score 1):

You could access `fields` with `$scholen[$index]->translations[$index]->fields`, however you couldn't access the title property since the whole value of `fields` is a string - you would have to strip the string to get the bit you wanted.

You would have to `get()` the results for the query, and then sort the results by  including this logic inside a `sortBy()` callback, e.g.

```
$scholen->sortBy(function ($value, $key) {
    // Logic here to get the part of the `fields` string you want
    // and then sort it
});
```

Hope this helps, this looks like a bit of a tricky one